# Get currentTime from video.js

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am using the docs to get the current time of my video but it just outputs `0` when I do a console log whcih makes sense as when I page load the video is at `0` is there a way I can like watch the time and if I pause it or at the end get the video time?

the reason why I ask I am trying to get the time to monitor if my users have actually watched it to the end and I have not used this library before:

```
<video id="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-controls-enabled" poster="http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/poster.jpg" data-setup="{}" controls="">
    <source src="sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <p class="vjs-no-js">Javascript was disabled or not supported</p>
</video>


<script type="text/javascript">

var myPlayer = videojs('videoPlayer');

    var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime();
        console.log(whereYouAt);

</script>
```

console.log gives me `0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`timeupdate`**](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#Eventstimeupdate) event

> *Fired when the current playback position has changed * During playback this is fired every 15-250 milliseconds, depending on the playback technology in use.*

```js
var myPlayer = videojs('videoPlayer');
myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function() {
  console.log(this.currentTime());
});
```

Comment: Thanks man that worked like a charm, is there a way I can store that in a variable and out put that figure?